# Send custom HTTP request header with HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, audio, streaming

Is it possible to send custom HTTP request headers using the HTML5 audio tag? I'm especially interested in sending a HTTP Range header, so the webserver will only stream parts of an mp3 file. I couldn't find a way to do that in the [audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp) api.

Answer (score 11):

If you're okay not supporting older browsers like IE, you can do this now with a service worker. Intercept the fetch request in the service worker and send it onwards with the custom header. Here is a basic example of intercepting a request to Google Drive and adding the Bearer token.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if(event.request.url === 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileID?alt=media') {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request.url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer myBearerToken",
            },
            redirect: "follow"
        })
    );    
  }
});
```

Edit: 2018-11-17 - Added how this won't work with older browsers.

Comment: How does this work with the audio tag? It doesn't seem to be firing a fetch event.

Comment: This really should not have upvotes as it is not a solution to the question as the audio tag does not fire a fetch event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events

Answer (score 6):

Not according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio), you can't. Audio tag is actually very inflexible.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the broad question... that will depend on what kind of request exactly.

What you want[ed] to do is actually very possible. You can simply add a `#t=start[,end]` [Media Fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#media-fragment-syntax) to any media url, and the browser will know it will have to only play from these timestamps:

```html
<!-- only from 23s to 27s -->
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8c9m92u1euqnkaz/GershwinWhiteman-RhapsodyInBluePart1.mp3#t=23,27" controls></audio>
```

And since I came from <s>the future</s> a question that did ask about sending authorization along with the media request, here is a link to some docs about the [crossOrigin attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/crossOrigin), which will also make your HTTP request with *"custom headers"*.