# HTML5 Audio source with special headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, streaming

The thing is: I need to play a streaming sound with HTML5 using audio tag, but the problem is that to access that sound I have to request a REST API that need an special header in the request.
So the source audio is in: http://mydomain.com/aapi/source/1234
But it only works if I request it with some header like this:

```
'x-sk-apiKey' : 'APIKey',
'x-sk-version' : '1.0',
'x-sk-client' : 'iPhone',
'x-sk-device-id' : 'device-id'
'x-sk-device-id' : 'device-id'
'x-sk-token' : '12332424r3fwd23r2cdscadscsd234234'
```

Is it posible to set audio src attribute to some javascript function like:

```
<script>

onButtonClick(){
  audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.src=ajax.requestWithHeader('http://mydomain.com/aapi/source/1234');
  audio.play();
}
</script>
```

In this case, setting up something like a PHP proxy for doing the request is not allowed.

Thanks!!
Nacho

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send custom HTTP request header with HTML5 audio tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299189/send-custom-http-request-header-with-html5-audio-tag)