# How to play authenticated audio stream in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

We have an audio stream API which takes `Basic Authentication`. On successful authentication, it returns the Audio stream with `"audio/mpeg"` MIME.

We were using the `<audio>` tag in HTML to play audio files earlier but now with authentication, the  tag no longer works. The `<audio>` tag spec does not allow "Authentication" header [See this StackOverflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299189/send-custom-http-request-header-with-html5-audio-tag)

If `<audio>` tag not helpful here what is the alternative way to play the audio with authentication on web?

Comment: Normally the [crossOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/crossOrigin) attribute is meant for that, you'd have to save the authorization in a cookie on the client before-hand. But I have to admit I'm more used to "anonymous" than "use-credentials" side of the attribute...

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the reply, The audio stream API is hosted on the same server, not on the different server. But it is only available if request header has "Authorization=Basic +token" and unfortunately audio tag doesn't have any provision for sending a header along with src URL

Answer (score 0):

Use URL format https://username:password@example.com/your_stream in the source tags, this sends the credentials in "Authorization" header.

Comment: I doubt this will be an insecure way of doing this coz we are putting username:password in the URL :)

Comment: Sending the username and password in the URL for SRC attributes is not recomended mate