# addEventListener('fetch', callback) never fires callback in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, addeventlistener

I'm trying to intercept `fetch` in my React app with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299189/send-custom-http-request-header-with-html5-audio-tag/52771341#52771341)

```
window.addEventListener('fetch', event => { console.log("FETCH CAPTURED"); } );
```

But I never see the `FETCH CAPTURED` log. Is it possible to intercept `fetch` **not** in service worker?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Where is this code in the context of your app?

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz not sure I've understood correctly. 
The app has structure looks like this: `App->Provider->AppRouter->Layout->(...)`. I call this code in Layout.componentWillMount() method

Comment: @ziwert are you using CRA? If you don't know how to check, go to package.json and check if you have ```react-scripts```

Comment: @NicolasHevia there is only `react-scripts-ts` in package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'fetch'` is a supported event / argument by the [`ServiceWorker#addEventListener`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers) method. It does not seem to be an event that has any meaning to the [`ElementTarget#addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method, which is the method invoked when you call `document.addEventListener`. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) is a list of supported methods.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use  [cra-append-sw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-append-sw) to append your code to the Service Worker automatically.

---

From the documentation:

> Utility tool to append custom code to ServiceWorker created by Create React App.
>   It allows to keep the default CRA configuration (no ejecting). It simply appends custom code to the ServiceWorker file created by CRA build scripts. By default, it bundles the code using very basic Webpack+Babel configuration (this can be omitted; see options).

**Usage**: 
`$ cra-append-sw [options] <file>`

**Usage with create-react-app**:

```
"start": "react-scripts start && cra-append-sw --mode dev ./custom-sw.js",
"build": "react-scripts build && cra-append-sw ./custom-sw.js",
```

---

You can also add your code manually in the generated file (without using cra-append-sw), but you'd need to do this every time you want to build your project.

Comment: It's a useful tool I think, but not works for me. I don't want build a service-worker from several scripts, I would like to capture `fetch` in my reactjs code and interested is it possible or not.